# Argonaut: decoding a polymorphic array

Tags: json, scala, argonaut

The JSON object for which I'm trying to write a `DecodeJson[T]` contains an array of different "types" (meaning the JSON structure of its elements is varying). The only common feature is the `type` field which can be used to distinguish between the types. All other fields are different. Example:

```
{
    ...,
    array: [
        { type: "a", a1: ..., a2: ...},
        { type: "b", b1: ...},
        { type: "c", c1: ..., c2: ..., c3: ...},
        { type: "a", a1: ..., a2: ...},
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

Using argonaut, is it possible to map the JSON array to a Scala `Seq[Element]` where `Element` is a supertype of suitable case classes of type `ElementA`, `ElementB`  and so on?

I did the same thing with `play-json` and it was quite easy (basically a `Reads[Element]` that evaluates the `type` field and accordingly forwards to more specific `Reads`). However, I couldn't find a way to do this with argonaut.

---

**edit: example**

Scala types (I wish to use):

```
case class Container(id: Int, events: List[Event])

sealed trait Event
case class Birthday(name: String, age: Int) extends Event
case class Appointment(start: Long, participants: List[String]) extends Event
case class ... extends Event
```

JSON instance (not under my control):

```
{
   "id":1674,
   "events": {
      "data": [
         {
            "type": "birthday",
            "name": "Jones Clinton",
            "age": 34
         },
         {
            "type": "appointment",
            "start": 1675156665555,
            "participants": [
               "John Doe",
               "Jane Doe",
               "Foo Bar"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a small function to help you build a decoder that handles this format.

See below for an example.

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

def decodeByType[T](encoders: (String, DecodeJson[_ <: T])*) = {
  val encMap = encoders.toMap

  def decoder(h: CursorHistory, s: String) =
    encMap.get(s).fold(DecodeResult.fail[DecodeJson[_ <: T]](s"Unknown type: $s", h))(d => DecodeResult.ok(d))

  DecodeJson[T] { c: HCursor =>
    val tf = c.downField("type")

    for {
      tv   <- tf.as[String]
      dec  <- decoder(tf.history, tv)
      data <- dec(c).map[T](identity)
    } yield data
  }
}

case class Container(id: Int, events: ContainerData)
case class ContainerData(data: List[Event])

sealed trait Event
case class Birthday(name: String, age: Int) extends Event
case class Appointment(start: Long, participants: List[String]) extends Event

implicit val eventDecoder: DecodeJson[Event] = decodeByType[Event](
  "birthday" -> DecodeJson.derive[Birthday],
  "appointment" -> DecodeJson.derive[Appointment]
)

implicit val containerDataDecoder: DecodeJson[ContainerData] = DecodeJson.derive[ContainerData]
implicit val containerDecoder: DecodeJson[Container] = DecodeJson.derive[Container]

val goodJsonStr =
  """
    {
       "id":1674,
       "events": {
          "data": [
             {
                "type": "birthday",
                "name": "Jones Clinton",
                "age": 34
             },
             {
                "type": "appointment",
                "start": 1675156665555,
                "participants": [
                   "John Doe",
                   "Jane Doe",
                   "Foo Bar"
                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    }
  """

def main(args: Array[String]) = {
  println(goodJsonStr.decode[Container])

  // \/-(Container(1674,ContainerData(List(Birthday(Jones Clinton,34), Appointment(1675156665555,List(John Doe, Jane Doe, Foo Bar))))))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that there is not a single sub-object (such as `data`) - instead, all the payload is on the same hierachical level. I edited the example in my question.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. I updated my original post with a new decoder that should handle what you need.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. My classes look a bit different and I couldn't make it work. Maybe we can start a final try - I added a complete example above. Big thanks.

Comment: I made another edit to reflect your actual format. Hopefully we got it this time!